# Missing "MSVCR120.dll" during the Installation of MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE

Tags: installation, mysql-workbench

When I install **MySQL Workbench 6.3** into my Windows 8.1, I encounter the following System Error :

[image: Error Image]

I already tried to redownload and reinstall the program but this error dialog appears every time. How to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

I am getting the same error and I installed using MSI.

Downloaded the VC redist packages for x64 and it fixed the issue:

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Strange that the error message has python.exe as it's title.

Comment: You must also download VC redist packages for x86 in order for Workbench to work well.

Answer (score 4):

You probably "installed" from the zip package, which does not do any validation of the available prerequisites for MySQL Workbench. I strongly recommend to use the [Windows Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) (or at least the msi) which check if the VC++ 2013 runtime is installed (which includes the mentioned DLL). The installer also allows for easy upgrades and helps you with the setup.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found the missing dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder. Just copy it to System32 and was fixed.

If you still have the @MikeW error with python.exe is because you have a 32bits version of one and the 64bits of the other (Python and Workbench).

Comment: For me, the dll was missing in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder, so I installed Visual C++ Redistributable Packages 32 bit package and the problem was solved.